# I am trying to make an if else statement which will echo 'complete'

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I believe the problem is with my if statement. I'm would like the code to echo complete when the specific values for testname and student name are present in the database, else show the testname as not completed. With my present code, the last echo statement keeps coming up no matter what testname and name I put.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Quiz results </title>


<?php 
// Created Aug 14th to workout Lesson list to disappear when test is finished

DEFINE ('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
DEFINE ('DB_USER', 'root');
DEFINE ('DB_PSWD', '');
DEFINE ('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
DEFINE ('DB_NAME', 'ccgate_amendb5');

$dbcon = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PSWD, DB_NAME);
$db = 'ccgate_amendb5';

mysql_select_db("$db") or die(mysql_error());

echo " <h1> YOU ARE Connected now !! </h1>";

echo " Quiz Results active <br> <br> ********************<br>  ";



$query = mysql_query("select testname, name FROM kcpe15questions");



$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);


if ($row['kcse-hist-f2-04-01-02-urbanization'] && $row['name']=='Amen')
{ 
  echo 'Subject Completed'; 
}
else
{ 
  echo '<br> urbanization f2-04-01-02';
}


mysql_close($dbcon);

?>


</head>

<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where do you expect `$row['kcse-hist-f2-04-01-02-urbanization']` to come from, if you are not selecting a column of that name? Enable proper error_reporting __now__ – PHP would have already told you that this key does not exist if you had done that before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Believe your problem is the following..

```
$row['kcse-hist-f2-04-01-02-urbanization']
```

I should imagine that the above ain't a column name? $row is obtaining the column names of the database.

Your probably best off trying to obtain all of your information first, storing it somewhere, and then creating the if statement.

Comment: So I should have $row['testname'] instead of ['kcse-hist-f2-04-02-urbanization']?  If so, then how will PHP know which testname I want? There are several testname files like kcse-hist-f2... .

Comment: You are right. kcse-hist-f2.... is a test withing the column 'testname'.  I want the else to echo 'subject completed' when it sees this testname and this name on the same row.

Answer (score 1):

You are not selecting column 'kcse-hist-f2-04-01-02-urbanization' in your query, so your `else` statement is being executed all the time.

```
$query = mysql_query("select testname, name , kcse-hist-f2-04-01-02-urbanization FROM kcpe15questions");
$row= mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
if ($row['kcse-hist-f2-04-01-02-urbanization'] && $row['name']=='Amen')
{ 
 echo 'Subject Completed'; 
}
```

Comment: kcse-hist-f2-04-01-02-urbanization is one of the test names inside the testname column.